# OverFlow Exception in OLEDB

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I am getting an error while i am trying to insert a user id of my client in the ms access database.

The error i am getting is Overflow.

when i am trying to insert its getting the above error.

I am using these code.

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into UserInfo " + "([firstname], [lastname], [gender], [occupation], [expirydate], [UserId], [phoneno]) " + " values('" + txt_FirstName.Text + "','" + txt_LastName.Text + "','" + cmb_Gender.Text + "','" + cmb_Occupation.Text + "','" + txt_expiryDate.Text + "','" + txt_HardDiskId.Text + "','" + txt_PhoneNo.Text +  "');", con);
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from UserInfo where (HardDiskId='" + txt_HardDiskId.Text + "')", con);
        int temp = 0;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string count = (string)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
            if ((count == "") || (count == null))
            {
                temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (temp > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("User ID of " + txt_FirstName.Text + " " + txt_LastName.Text + " has been added");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record not added");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User ID of " + txt_FirstName.Text + " already exists. Try another user ID.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What line are you getting this error? Can you post the _exact_ error/exception message?

Comment: temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); at this line

Comment: By the way, concatenating strings for SQL is not a good idea. Your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: i am getting exactly this error and just Overflow not more than that

Comment: can u please say me where i am going wrong because i have not get such an error before

Comment: I can't tell without more detail. Can you post the value of the SQL command that is in `cmd` when you get the error?

Comment: i cant understand what u are saying can u please say me clearly

Comment: You are setting a SQL command - what is the command when the full string has been created? It starts with `INSERT` - what is the whole thing after `txt_FirstName.Text` and the other fields have been concatenated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from being open to SQL Injection (which you should parameterize your OleDbCommand), first thought on a problem is what you are trying to store the data.  Do any of the text fields have special characters or apostrophe in name which would otherwise pre-terminate your embedded .... '" + nextField + "' ..." entries and throw the balance off.

Another... don't know if the parser is picky or not... but a space after values, before open paren.... " values("  to " values (".

Third, and more probable the issue is the expiration date.  If its a date field, and you are trying to put in as text, it might be failing on the data type conversion.